# Xpage the Domino bookmarks nsf

Tags: xpages

I am trying to create an XPage version of the domino bookmarks.nsf used for creating the home page in the client. The users want to be able to see their most used databases with a link to go straight there.

Does anybody know how the domino favorites works and how to consume data from it?

Comment: Congratulations! You asked the 1000th XPages question on Stackoverflow!!!

Comment: There is an interesting project on OpenNTF called [XPages HomePage](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20HomePage) which allows bookmarking of databases just like Lotus Notes workspace. You might have a look at that to get some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The bookmark.nsf is beaten in mystery only by the desktop.dsk :-)
All entries in the Open button are stored as Outline design elements. Outlines are read/write in the LotusScript/Java/SSJS API, so you could grab them in a SSJS library. I don't know when/how the favorites are updated